# How to display ng-repeat elements only if user uses filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would know how to display my elements only if a user uses some filter.

For example:

```
$scope.elements = [{name : 'Pablo', age : 23}, {name : 'Franco', age : 98}];

<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" />
<div ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:searchText">
      <p>{{ element.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Here I don't want to display the filtered list if users haven't write into the input type text tag.
Or the same with input type checkbox, radio, select tag...

What I could do is to use ng-show directive

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:searchText" ng-show="searchText.length > 0">
      <p>{{ element.name }}</p>
</div>
```

But it does not seem legit.

Any better idea ? or obviously, a native solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why ``ng-repeat`` + ``ng-show`` isn't legit?

Comment: do u have a jsfiddle for dis?

Comment: It seems too tricky, because angular should have a native directive to do the job.

No jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this

```
$scope.elements = [{name : 'Pablo', age : 23}, {name : 'Franco', age : 98}];

<input type="text" ng-model="searchText.name" />
<div ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:searchText">
      <p>{{ element.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ng-if that way the code doesn't run until the condition is met.

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elements | filter:searchText" ng-if="searchText.length > 0">
      <p>{{ element.name }}</p>
</div>
```